# Can I make my x-axis display in hh:mm:ss.ms format?

Tags: c++, qt, charts

I'm currently working in qt charts and the x-axis is displaying time in a second format but I would like it to display the x-axis values in hh:mm:ss.ms format. Is there a way to do change my axis so it displays in this format?

I've followed this example : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch

But my axis is currently only displaying 0:00 which is strange

The following method appends the new values correctly to the graph by using createDefaultAxes() but for some reason it cannot correctly do so for my other custom axis.

```cpp
void RecordWidgetGraph::setBitrate (qint64 bitrate, qint64 duration){
    // Appends new values and updates graph
    if(bitrate != 0){

        double timestampDouble = (double) duration /1000;
        double bitrateDouble = (double) bitrate /1000000;

        lineSeries->append(timestampDouble, bitrateDouble);
        this->chart()->removeSeries(lineSeries);
        this->chart()->addSeries(lineSeries);

        this->chart()->createDefaultAxes();

        QDateTimeAxis *axisX = new QDateTimeAxis;
        axisX->setFormat("m:ss");
        axisX->setTickCount(10);
        this->chart()->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
        lineSeries->attachAxis(axisX);

        this->chart()->scroll(chartCounter /5 , 0);
        this->chart()->axisX()->setRange(timestampDouble - 10, timestampDouble + 2);

        chartCounter++;
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like at the moment. The first axis displays the time in s.ms but the DateTimeAxis is displaying only 0:00.

[image]

this is my setupGraph method which creates the graph.

```
QChart* RecordWidgetGraph::setupGraph(){

lineSeries = new QLineSeries();
timeSeries = new QTime();

// Create chart, add data, hide legend, and add axis
Chart * chart = new Chart();

chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(lineSeries);
chart->createDefaultAxes();

// Customize the title font
QFont font;
font.setPixelSize(3);
chart->setTitleFont(font);
chart->setTitleBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
//   chart->setTitle("Bitrate per second mbps");

// Change the line color and weight
QPen pen(QRgb(0x000000));
pen.setWidth(1);
lineSeries->setPen(pen);

this->setChart(chart);
//  this->chart()->axisX()->setTitleText("Seconds");

this->chartCounter = 0;

bitrateTimer.start();

return(chart);


}
```

Comment: But maybe you must set the min and max values as well?

Comment: I've included the entire method now including the "correctly working" x-axis

Comment: what is the value of `duration`?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's the timestamp in milliseconds divided by 1000 to get it in seconds.ms .

Comment: that is in your formula, what I want to know is what the range of values takes duration? to be able to implement an MCVE since your code is not.

Comment: @eyllanesc It takes everything from 0 to max value of long long int depending on how long the program has been running, and it is intended to run for extended periods of time. It increases by 1000 for every second passed.

Comment: @hyde I'm currently just trying to make it print it in any time format. According to this it should be fine I think https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString-2 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeaxis.html